# No appropriate default constructor available with template implementation in Cpp

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement Stack by hand in C++. I want to use this implementation for many datatypes so that I've tried to implement it by using template in C++. Then I come to an error with my constructor of my Stack class.
Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    
    Node(T value)
    {
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Stack :public Node<T>
{
public:
    Node<T>* head;
    Stack()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        Node<T>* current = head;
        Node<T>* next;
        while (current != NULL) {
            next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }

        head = NULL;
    }

    T top()
    {
        return head->data;
    }

    void push(Node<T>* newNode)
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    void pop()
    {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return head == NULL;
    }
};
```

And the error is: 'Node': no appropriate default constructor available

Can you guys explain what is happening and give me some advices!!!

Comment: Why is stack derived from a node? Is stack a node?

Comment: `Stack` should not derive from `Node`. The error you're getting is because you never call the `Node` constructor from the `Stack` constructor (so it defaults to the empty ctor which does not exist)

Comment: Do not use `NULL`, in C++ you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: I forget to remove this. I've fixed it. Thanks you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack class should not inherit Node class, it should compose it, you should delete the inheritance relation from stack class, it should look like this:

```
template <class T>
class Stack
```

Answer (score 1):

When an object is created that derives from a base class then also the base class subobject is created. This:

```
Stack()
{
    head = NULL;
}
```

is the same as writing:

```
Stack() : Node<T> () {
    head = NULL;
}
```

That is: When you do not explicitly call the base class constructor then its default constructor is called. Your `Node` has no default constructor (a default constructor is one that can be called without parameters).

Actually it looks like `Stack` should not inherit from `Node` in the first place.

As a side note, you should initialize members instead of assignment in the constructors body. One way to initialize them is the the member initialization list. And better use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`:

```
Stack() : Node<T>(), head(nullptr) 
{}
```

*PS* You'd get the same error if there were no templates involved. I suggest to write the same code for one specific type and then turn it into a template. In this way you can do one thing at a time.